# Sonarqube 6.2 - multilanguage setup, show coverage per language

Tags: continuous-integration, sonarqube

We do have an pretty old code base, where at the moment everything is handled within (frontend/backend) - to improve our quality, we setup a multilanguage project, now instead of analyzing just Java, we also analyse SCSS, HTML, JS, Xml,...

Well so far everything is running smooth, and working as expected, I am just curious if there is a way to show "coverage per language"? We do have a lot of Java Tests but no JavaScript tests, and it would be pretty neat, to have an overview of "how much tested" the different languages are!

There is also some kind of business value related to this! As the Coverage is now not separated into Integration and Unit tests, it is now also factoring the coverage of the JavaScript files into the overall coverage -> which we can argument easily, but we lose some kind of comparability :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not available synthetically within SonarQube. If it's really important to you, you'll need to use the [web services](https://sonarqube.com/web_api) to pull the data and do the calculations externally.